# Strict HTML strips CSS classes in a custom block

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I created a custom block using *Strict HTML* (and adding `<div>` and other tags to the allowed HTML). If I look at the frontend, it strips all the CSS classes like `<div class="myclass">`.

What do I have to do to create this block with all the CSS classes, and the custom HTML markup?

Comment: are you creating the block with the UI or programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default custom blocks in Drupal 8 use the *Basic HTML* text format. Using either *Basic HTML* or *Restricted HTML* will remove any class attributes.

You need to set your format to *Full HTML* to prevent Drupal from stripping out these attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I update my question. What is your advice?

Comment: That question is off topic here; Drupal Answers sticks to questions about Drupal. What you're asking is a web design question.

Comment: No I don't ask how to style it. I want to know how I set it up in Drupal 8? Because when I make my own HTML format and add HTML I need it's strips all the CSS classes?

Comment: As the answer states, setting the block Text Format to _Full HTML_ prevents Drupal from stripping out class attributes.

Comment: Yes, this is correct: _Strict HTML_ allows you to set which tags should be allowed, but not which attributes those tags should accept. `class` inside a HTML tag is an attribute.

Comment: What he and I too, want to know is how to setup "full html" in a custom block you create programmatically. When you code you don't have the nice dropdown. Is there some attribute like #format in the render array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your format to Full HTML to prevent Drupal from stripping out these attributes. I think it does not working when you backup data and deployed website .